# error message when opening synaptic source list line 57

Tags: command-line, synaptic, source

it seems there is a problem in my source list which I cant find;
everytime I try to open synaptic this error appears:

```
E: Malformed line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Go to the repository dialog to correct the problem.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

on opening my source list, line 57 doesnt seem to exist, this is it;

(Im a new user and can only post two hyperlinks - these are the last two lines and I suspect one of them is the problem...)

```
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com partner
```

I have tried seraching for a solution and have found similar problems, just not sure which line I should delete/replace...

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse>

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse>

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner>

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com partner
```

Comment: If you put your lines in a code block (see help) those will not be counted as links.

Comment: « To create code blocks or other preformatted text, indent by four spaces. » Backticks are intended for inline code span.

Answer (score 1):

Your second line lacks the distribution version (quantal) between the URL and `partner`.

Edit: In your entire file, each entry must be of the form:

```
deb|deb-src URL distrib archive [archive […]]
```

Line 29:

```
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse>
```

should be:

```
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse
```

Line 44:

```
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse>
```

should be:

```
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
```

Line 51 (doesn't matter since it is commented out):

```
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner>
```

should be:

```
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
```

Line 57 (last one):

```
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com partner
```

should be:

```
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com quantal partner
```

The rest seems correct. I didn't validate it with aptitude, though.